# Save bean variable in string in JSP

Tags: jsp, struts, javabeans

I have a bean file named "FormBean.java". "FormAction" and "FormService" are the action and service files.
In my project which is based on Struts1, in the JSP file "Details.jsp", I am doing this:

```
<bean:write name="FormBean" property="email" />
```

to print the user's email in the view.
The FormBean file contains the getter and setter methods of the fields in the form.

Is there a way to save the email into a String and reuse it ?
I dont want to use EL.

Answer (score 1):

You can define new variable emailStr

```
<bean:define id="emailStr" name="FormBean" property="email" />
```

and later use it

```
<bean:write name="emailStr" />
```

or

```
${emailStr}
```